# Como crear y leer archivos yaml en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo entendido que en python para ser más ordenado se usan archivos .yaml.
El problema es que no se como leerlos ni crearlos. Alguno me puede ayudar?

Comment: a que te refieres con ser mas ordenado?

Comment: ósea para declarar las variables ahi para tener todo mas comodo

Comment: Te recomendaria hacer una búsqueda en la red: `como leer yaml desde python`, y por ejemplo encontraras el siguiente tutorial: https://wiki.python.org/moin/YAML

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos bibliotecas diferentes que te permiten interactuar con el formato YAML: [`pyYAML`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) y [ruamel.yaml](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) que es un *fork* del anterior.

He probado ambos y en mi experiencia `ruamel.yaml` es más completo y sobre todo más veloz a la hora de "digerir" ficheros yaml grandes. No obstante puede ser más difícil de instalar porque no está escrito en python puro (tiene partes en C).

En cualquier caso, al margen de qué módulos uses para generarlo o leerlo, un comentario general sobre YAML. Es un formato de datos equivalente en capacidad a JSON. Es decir, te permite almacenar en un fichero y en un formato fácil de leer para personas, datos que básicamente serán del tipo diccionario (cuyas claves sólo pueden ser cadenas) o listas. Los valores del diccionario o de la lista pueden ser numéricos, booleanos, cadenas, o bien otro diccionario o lista.

La diferencia con JSON es la sintaxis, más sencilla de escribir "a mano" en un editor al hacer innecesarias las comillas alrededor de las cadenas, las comas separando valores en una lista o diccionario, y las llaves o corchetes para delimitar dónde empieza y acaba cada lista o diccionario. En lugar de ello, usará retornos de carro como separadores y la indentación como marcador sintáctico.

Así, por ejemplo, el siguiente JSON:

```
{ "configuracion": {
      "IPs": [ "127.0.0.1",
               "192.168.0.1"
             ],
      "puerto": 8000,
      "nombre": "miservidor.com"
   }
}
```

Se escribiría así en YAML:

```
configuracion:
  IPs:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 192.168.0.1
  puerto: 8000
  nombre: miservidor.com
```

Que es (probablemente) más fácil de leer y sobre todo de escribir. Aunque YAML tiene su complicación si queremos que el valor sea una cadena que ocupe varias líneas. Puede hacerlo, pero la sintaxis se va volviendo más farragosa.

Una vez leído el fichero anterior con un parser YAML (cualquiera de los dos que indiqué antes), lo que tendrás sería un diccionario python "normal", llamémosle `d`, a partir del cual puedes acceder, por ejemplo al puerto, con `d["configuracion"]["puerto"]`, o a la primera IP con `d["configuracion"]["IPs"][0]`, etc.

Considera si te merecerá más la pena usar directamente la versión JSON en lugar de la YAML. Si tu fichero de configuración no es muy complejo, la sintaxis JSON tampoco es tan farragosa y la ventaja es que el parser `json` ya viene con python y no tienes que instalar nada extra.